# Layout problem in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comments, fonts

There is a problem when showing text of an answer comment.

If you look at [my comment here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47929/problem-defining-a-new-command-using-lstinputlisting#comment98786_47933), the text should read:

> ...  right, this is because of the `_`. For some reason ..

But the underscore is hidden by my username on the next line. It is a bit weird.

---

Screenshot by doncherry (Win 7 FF 10.0.2)

[image: half-hidden underscore]

Screenshot by Jonas (Win 7, Chrome 18)

[image: Chrome 18]

Comment: Yes, the underscore is half-hidden, i.e. overlaid by the shaded box of the user name. I added a screenshot. Reducing the vertical height of the user name-box might help, if it doesn't screw up the entire design.

Comment: I added a screenshot using Chrome 18. (I just add to edit the html to add a word otherwise the _ would have been shifted, but the problem exists)

Comment: @doncherry: Oh man, you were a little bit faster. Here it’s also partly hidden, but not exactly as in your screenshot. I can see about three quarter of the gray square’s bottom.

Comment: Win XP, FF3.6.27: It is not hidden, but just because `Jonas` is some characters to the right of `_`, otherwise it would be hidden, too. (Thus, confirming the problem.)

Answer (score 9):

I have increased the line-height in comment section slightly so the code and owner blocks don't overlap. The change will be in the next production build.

Comment: I think this degrades the readability of the comments.  It's certainly not as aesthetically pleasing with the larger line height.

Comment: @AlanMunn I only increased it by couple of pixels. It's a great departure from before IMO.

Comment: I agree with @Alan. Would it be possible to _decrease_ the size of the boxes, i.e. make the fit the text more snugly? (And return to the former line height.)